# Can i use python OS /system modules inside django

Tags: python, django, linux

I want to know that if i build a website in django then inside any django script can i use something like

`os.listdir(path)`

and get contents there or do i need to do something else to make that work?

Comment: -1 for not trying it out yourself before asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine. Why don't you try it?

Comment: Actually i am thinking of learning django only if thats possible. i am fed up of using php and python together. I used php just of web interface. If i can call low level system stuff inside web scripts with same function then i will be very happy. I just want to call `backup(username)` from web rather than using exec function to call py script to call that function. I really love python